# Symfony2: Form specify range of Date

Tags: forms, symfony

I use **`date and datetime widget`** into my `formular`, but the default values doen't suit me.

I don't know how to specify a date range into my **`ObjectType`**.

on the one hand I want to change date to specify a **date range**:

*for example*

```
- from 2012-10-1 to 2022-10-1
```

On the other hand I want to specify the minutes like that

**`0 - 10 - 20 -30-40 - 50`**

Please help me

See ya

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just symply precise in the type 'years' value, and it will be ok :)